# Building xCode project on real device after getting it from friend

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm trying to run my project on my iphone, this project was built and run sucessfully, I had some problem Therefore I sent the project to my friend and he sent me back without the problem ( just a programmer thing ), now whenever I try to run it on my real device ( iphone 11 ) I get two errors saying: `No account for team "X". Add a new account in the Accounts preference pane or verify that your accounts have valid credentials.`
`No profiles for '-.finalProject' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching '-. finalProject'.`

any solutions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All projects have project settings for signing the app. Your friend changed it to his, so he could build. You need to change it back to yours. (It's not possible to have "nothing" as the setting.)

You need to

- select your project in the Project Navigator (folder list on left).
- Click on your Target.
- Click on "Signing & Capabilities"
- You want to change the Team selection

[image: Example]